# A question on Coclosed Categories

Tags: category-theory

I have to show that a category $\mathcal{C}$ is coclosed if and only if it has an initial object, a coproduct for every set of objects, and a coequalizer for every pair of morphisms sharing the same domain and codomain.

Now, here's my dilemna. I have no idea what coclosed means, and I've been unable to find any source which gives me an exact definition. And even apart from that, I have no idea how to approach this question. Any help is appreciated, even if it's as limited as providing me with definitions of the terms mentioned in the question.

Comment: I think coclosed should be *cocomplete*.

Comment: ...Where did you encounter such a problem, that you don't have the definition of the words you're being asked to prove things about?

Comment: This actually is an assignment question from a course, where I wasn't able to attend some classes which is when these concepts were discussed. The professor uses personal notes which he hasn't made available. So, I'm in bit of a pickle

Comment: @ArnaudD I see, I'll have to clarify the question with my professor then. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked up *cocomplete* categories? It's the usual term for what you call 'coclosed'.

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks!